# How can I get the attribute value based on sibling attribute value from a json response?

Tags: web-services, rest-assured

This is my response.

```
[
      {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "text1"
      },
      {
        "id": 456,
        "name": "text2"
      },
      {
        "id": 789,
        "name": "text3"
      }
    ]
```

I can just provide the name value and want to get back the id attribute. I am using rest assured. I can create a map and then get it accordingly but searching for solutions like jsonPath().get(id where name ="text2"). Just thinking if anything can be done like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditions like .find{it.name=='text2'}.id

Comment: is there any online evaluator for checking the json paths?